# How to handle $_POST results of autosuggest multi-input on form

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have the following JsFiddle to help with my question:

http://jsfiddle.net/eY2yH/3/

I am ultimately trying to create a simple input field which allows a user to enter multiple 'names' which creates a message to those users on our system. In many ways, this should function EXACTLY as Composing an email in Gmail (enter text for a user name/email, the autosuggests appears, then allow for additional input or submit).

When I run the code given, the results of the $_POST are quite strange.

Depending on which members are selected, the value of the key changes:

array([as-results-0XXX]=>1,2,3,4)

where XXX varies and 1,2,3,4 would represent the value of the members selected. These values are stored in a single element and separated by comma. In the end, I want to run through a loop for each user selected and send the necessary alert:

If 3 members are selected, e.g.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   do table insert with particular value
}
```

My site is built with php and clearly using jquery. I have done a bit of searching and can find nothing regarding multiple inputs on the same autosuggest field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way the name of the hidden input is determined by adding the `asHtmlID` attribute to your `.autoSuggest()`:

```
$("input.autoSuggest").autoSuggest(data.items, {
    selectedItemProp: "name",
    searchObjProps: "name",
    asHtmlID: "custom_id"
});
```

The variable posted to your php script will be available through `$_POST['as_values_custom_id']`